# QFileSystemModel freezes UI

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, qt

I'm using Qt 4.8 and trying to create a GUI showing one or more directory tree.
I read in a documentation that the `QFileSystemModel` uses separate thread.
I tried this:

```
QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel;
model->setRootPath("C:/");
connect(model, SIGNAL(directoryLoaded(QString)), this, SLOT(alertLoaded(QString)));
ui->treeViewFolders->setModel(model);
```

Here `alertLoaded` only shows a message dialog when a directory is loaded.
So if I have right, when I'm trying to open a new directory branch in the tree, then it must load the items of the directory in the background so, that the UI is not freezed during the process.

But the problem is that it not seems to act like this. When I'm trying to open a directory with a 1000 or more files (e.g. system32), it freezes for a few seconds. Obviously the icons are slowing down the loading, but if the model is using a separate thread, why does it freeze?

**The question:**

How can I tell the model, that I really want to use a separate thread OR that I don't want to wait to the other thread?

Comment: if you are shure that the `alertLoaded` slot does not block your ui, i would try to give the 'worker' a separated thread, make a signal to give the new model to your view and connect them. soo long zai

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, QFileSystemModel always uses a separate thread. Sounds to me like your view is locking down your system while it retrieves the entire file list and resets the layout as it adds every item. The post is a little old, but they talk about your issue a little [here](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt4-preview-feedback/2005-06/thread00029-0.html).

Do you have the same delays if you use a QListView? If you use a QListView instead of a QTreeView you can set it to run in batch mode with [QListView::setLayoutMode()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#LayoutMode-enum).

If you must have a QTreeView, you might consider subclassing it and using [QAbstractItemView::scheduleDelayedItemsLayout()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qabstractitemview.html#scheduleDelayedItemsLayout) to layout everything in one go.